# Eclipse Web Deployment Assembly does not copy /src folder into the specified Deploy Path

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-wtp

In my Deployment Assembly settings, I request that the contents of **/src** are deployed under **WEB-INF/classes**

[image]

However this doesn't work correctly. The contents of **/src** are copied in the **context root /**, instead of inside **/WEB-INF/classes/**

This happens if there is any entry that deploys to **/**. For example, if I remove entries **/s3Content** and **/www**, then **/src** gets deployed correctly into **/WEB-INF/classes**.

As a result, the webapp cannot be deployed correctly. Any ideas on what could be causing this?

---

UPDATE: I ended up reinstalling the latest version of Eclipse and now everything works fine

Comment: Sounds like a bug to be reported, but are you *sure* you want your source files put into `WEB-INF/classes` instead of the `.class` files from the build output folder?

Comment: Yes that's correct, that's how the Deployment Assembly works. It won't copy the .java files in the specified "Deploy Path", it will rather use it as a target path for the .class build output. The curious thing is that this used to work fine for a long time. The problem started only recently.